# JSON.Stringify replacer function not able to get key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using JSON.stringify and its replacer parameter. But in replacer parameter i am not able to get key and value, instead of i got key value as empty string "" and value as complete JSON object. What mistake i have done in my code? please clear it.

```
var replacer=function(key,value){
        debugger; 
    }
    $(function () {
       JSON.stringify({"name":'xxxxx'},replacer)
    });
```

I need to get key as "name" and value as "xxxxx"

Comment: Please show expected results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MDN - JSON.stringify(): The replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter):

> [...]Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object being stringified, and it then gets called for each property on the object or array being stringified.[...]

In your first iteration you get the whole object `{"name":'xxxxx'}` as `value`,
but because you return `undefined` from your replace function the whole object will be replaced by `undefined`, and because of that the next iteration with the value/key pairs does not take place.

If you return the `value` you will see that the next iteration takes place.

```
var replacer = function(key, value) {
  console.dir(arguments);
  return value;
}

JSON.stringify({
  "name1": 'xxxxx'
}, replacer);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var replacer=function(key,value){
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(value);
    var name = json_obj.name;

}
$(function () {
   JSON.stringify({"name":'xxxxx'},replacer)
});
```